# LibGDX Bouncing ball

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I want to create an infinite bouncing ball. For now I'm just trying to make the bouncing on Y (up & down).

This is my **GameWorld class**, you can see there is a method **collides** to detect the collision but How to make that **"circle"** go up?

```
public class GameWorld {

    private Circle rond;
    private Rectangle rect;

    public GameWorld(int midPointY) {
        rond = new Circle(100, midPointY - 5, 5);
        rect = new Rectangle(0, 200, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), 5);
    }

    public void update(float delta) {

        if(collides(rond)){

        }else
            rond.y++;

    }

    public boolean collides(Circle rond) {
        if (rect.y < rond.y + (rond.radius)*2) {
            return (Intersector.overlaps(rond, rect));
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Circle getRond() {
        return rond;

    }

    public Rectangle getRect() {
        return rect;
    }

}
```

Of course, I have another class GameRenderer that rendere these two objects

Comment: Add a vy variable, init it to 1. Instead of 'rond.y++' use 'rond.y += vy'. After collision, set the vy to -1. Same for x.

Comment: smthg like this? private vy = 1; (...) if(collides(rond)){
   vy = -1;
  }else
   rond.y += vy;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically with any kind of physics you want to store the speed of an object as well as its position.  That way, each time though your update loop you just have to change the y position by the y speed.  When the collision occurs, all you need to do is calculate the new `yspeed` and update `rond`.

```
public void update(float delta) {
    if(collides(rond)){
        rond.yspeed = -rond.yspeed;
    }else{
        rond.y+=rond.yspeed*delta;
    }
}
```

Comment: How to define the yspeed?

Comment: `yspeed` would be defined in `rond` as whatever you wanted the initial speed of `rond` to be.